# How can I group batches of records into separate QR codes - crystal 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, qr-code, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to create a QR code in the PF that contains the information of up to 15 records in one QR code. If there are 16-30 records in the report they need to be on a second page with a new QR code for these records. 31-45, 46-60 etc.

The QR code has a general header, followed by the data of up to 15 records (order #, part #, qty,) then finally a general footer.

The code I have now populates and scans. The trouble I am having is breaking the records apart into different pages/codes. I can get one page for all records or one page for each record.

The QR builder formula in the details section (adds the header, body, and trailer together):

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
evaluateafter ({@QRCode Header});
evaluateafter ({@Body1});
evaluateafter ({@Body2});
evaluateafter ({@Body3});
evaluateafter ({@Body4});
evaluateafter ({@QRCodeEoT});

if RecordNumber in (1 to 15) then {@QRCode Header}+ {@Body1a} +{@QRCodeEoT}
else if
   RecordNumber in (16 to 30) then {@QRCode Header}+ {@Body2a} +{@QRCodeEoT}
else if
   RecordNumber in (31 to 45) then {@QRCode Header}+ {@Body3a} +{@QRCodeEoT}
else if
   RecordNumber in (46 to 60) then {@QRCode Header}+ {@Body4a} +{@QRCodeEoT}
```

An example of the @Body1 formula, in Details:

```
Global StringVar Build1;

EvaluateAfter ({@BodyBuilder});

If RecordNumber in (1 to 15) then
Build1:= Build1 + {@BodyBuilder}
else Build1:=""
```

Body1a formula in PF truncates Body1 but it is not doing anything, Body 1 and Body 1a pull the same data..

```
Left({@Body1}, (if(Length({@Body1})- Length({@BodyBuilder})<=0) then 0 
else (Length ({@Body1})- Length ({@BodyBuilder}))))
```

I tried to replace {@BodyXa} in the QR builder with the respective global variable BuildX, to no avail. Also, the QR codes grow in size with 1 being the smallest, 15 being the largest, and at 16 it starts over again. Which makes me think they are accumulating e.g. 1st page has 1st record, 2nd page has 1st and 2nd records, so on.

I've been trying to change the way the variables build on each other, it seems like the records are not appending correctly.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show the sample data and how report need to look like?

Comment: @Siva 0615KT070184616P34158AL02AQ882PNA is an example of one record information, this the part that can be repeated up to 15 times for the page. 15K, P, Q, and 2P are identifiers for the different information pieces. 
Right now the report seems to pull more information than there are records.. it looks like it is duplicating some.

Comment: http://puu.sh/nhB4C/5c7905c2af.PNG is what the QR code should look like, the rest of the report is text fields. those body formulas are in the details section, BodyXa in the PF section as well as the QR code itself